# How to make cat command to view file content with syntax highlights in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, colors, syntax, cat

In the following screenshot, on executing the cat command it display the horizontal line then file info with name and then file content.

Is this feature from cat or any external lib?

I have found one python lib [Pygments](https://pygments.org/)

Could some geek tell me how to achieve this?
[image]

Comment: "on executing the cat command it display the horizontal line then file info with name and then file content" that's not what `cat` does.  Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy for why you wouldn't expect `cat` to do something like that.  I personally think it's a waste of your time as you can open your file in your favorite editor and get syntax highlighting, but if you want to do it you'll be building your own utility or finding another, not `cat`

Comment: @erik258
Thanks for your valuable information. I really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an hour of search on google, I found that eventually.

It is not a `cat` command. It is [bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) that is making all the things pretty.

Comment: It may be `cat` indeed but content of `dbg_iex.exs` contains control characters itself (e.g. created with `bat`).